# Agrupar elementos de un array por fechas

Tags: php, array

¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar en una tabla los elementos de ese `Array` que compartan la misma fecha, ejemplo los del `2019-01-01` y mostrar la suma de los importes de los elementos que tengan la misma fecha?

Tengo el `array` organizado de esta manera:

```
<?php 

$array=array(array('fecha' => '2019-01-01', 'nombre'=>'Pedro Gonzalez', 'importe' => '1500', 'concepto' => 'internet'),array('fecha' => '2019-01-01', 'nombre'=>'Pedro Gonzalez', 'deuda' => '5000', 'concepto' => 'alquiler'),array('fecha' => '2019-02-01', 'nombre'=>'Pedro Gonzalez', 'deuda' => '700', 'concepto' => 'Luz'),array('fecha' => '2019-02-01', 'nombre'=>'Pedro Gonzalez', 'deuda' => '300', 'Gas' => 'alquiler'),array('fecha' => '2019-01-01', 'nombre'=>'Pedro Gonzalez', 'deuda' => '600', 'concepto' => 'Agua'),array('fecha' => '2019-03-01', 'nombre'=>'Pedro Gonzalez', 'deuda' => '1000', 'concepto' => 'Colegio'));

?>
```

Comment: En que lenguaje lo tienes?

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo en PHP

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no existe una funcion de forma nativa, pero puedes implementar una que haga el trabajo, de la siguiente manera:

```php
function array_group_by( $arr, $fldName) {
    $groups = array();
    foreach ($arr as $rec) {
        $groups[$rec[$fldName]] = $rec;
    }
    return $groups;
}
```

O directamente en el código

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $element) {
    $result[$element['id']][] = $element;
}
```

Creditos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706359/php-array-group

Saludos